# asp.net wizard and user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have wizard control with multiple steps.
something like this

```
    <asp:wizard>
    <wizardsteps>

   </wizardsteps>
  <wizardsteps>

   </wizardsteps>
   <wizardsteps>
     <usercontrol>
   </wizardsteps>
```

the last step user control  is the issue which is loading every time page is posted  back and not just when particular step loads . that is making page slow. how can i possibly load  user control when particular step is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load your UC only when the step three is on, you can add an event in your Wizard and try something like this:

```
    protected void wizIndex_ActiveStepChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (wizIndex.ActiveStepIndex == 2)
            {
                //Load UC
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And then, you should remove the UC from your ASPX.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically load your control in the code behind, check this: [How to: Create Instances of ASP.NET User Controls Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx)